# couldn't find with 'id'= in rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am facing error `Couldn't find Course with 'id'=`.

Here is my course controller function of `manage_users`:

```
def manage_users
  @course_users = (@course.users + (User.where(admin: true))) - [current_user]
  @other_users =  @users.where(admin: false) - (@course_users + [current_user]) 
end

private
 # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
 def set_course
  @course = Course.find(params[:id])
 end
 # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
 def course_params
  params.require(:course).permit(:name, :start_date, :end_date, :branch_id)
 end
```

**routes.rb**

```
resources :courses do
  get 'manage_users'
  put 'add_user'
end
```

[image]

Comment: Post the code where you used `set_course` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing `set_course` method :

```
def set_course
 @course = Course.find(params[:course_id])
end
```

You are passing `course_id` in params, so you should fetch it like `params[:course_id]`.

*Currently you are doing it by `params[:id]`, so course can not be found with this id*

Comment: yes but if i change above, then my create and edit action wont work as in that its being passed as 
{"id"=>"1"}

Comment: @user3637820 you can change your view code accordingly. where you are doing like `your_path(course_id: @course.id)` , just change that to `your_path(id: @course.id)`.   **OR**  you can add another method and call that callback for `manage_users` using `before_action` or `before_filter`

Comment: thanks, that worked. also i had to update the routes as mentioned by jeff

Answer (score 1):

Your `before_filter` can't find `Course` with `id=1`.

```
def set_course
  @course = Course.find(params[:id])
end
```

Course id is being passed in `course_id` parameter.

```
def set_course
  @course = Course.find(params[:course_id])
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your routes.rb file:

```
resources :courses do
  member do
    get 'manage_users'
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

it will work for all actions

```
@course = Course.find_by(id: [params[:id], params[:course_id]])
```